# Unable to parse Cloud foundry logs along with json message

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration, elk, grok

We have a Java application that produces below log in cloud foundry (Refer Actual Cloud foundry Log Message). We have attached a syslog drain service to our cloud foundry instance. Logstash listens on the Cloud foundry logs port and config is unable to parse and store the below JSON message which is part of the actual cloud foundry log. I have shared the log message and our logstash configuration. We are able to parse this actual cloud foundry loge message as per the logstash configuration grok pattern in the online grok pattern validator tools.

Requirement is to store the below json message data as ,separte attribute in elastic search log message.

`**Json Message part of the actual cloud foundry log** {"responseCode":"200","traceId":"tron_service_1686560045388_PgYSu0QB","trackingId":"3500b846-0c9e-497d-a19f-bfa4256944b3"}`

`**Actual Cloud foundry Log Message** 15:49:05.543: [APP/PROC/WEB.0] [service] [xspgen-3500b846-0c9e-497d-a19f-bfa4256903b3] [c8c2305a-6314-44cc-bba0-b2c52f9babb4] [tron-service_1686565145388_PgYSu0QB] [qa] [http-nio-8080-exec-1] 2023-06-12 10:19:05.542  INFO - c.c.c.x.x.b.logging.LogCollector     : Final JSON log is {"responseCode":"200","traceId":"tron_service_1686560045388_PgYSu0QB","trackingId":"3500b846-0c9e-497d-a19f-bfa4256944b3"}`

**Logstash config**

```
input 
{
tcp {
tags => ['syslog']
port => 24514
}
udp 
{
tags => ['syslog']
port => 24514
codec => json
}
}

filter {
grok 
{
  match => { "message" => "%{DATA:data1}:%{DATA:data2}:%{DATA:data3}%{DATA:data4}: \[%{DATA:data5}] \[%{DATA:data6}] \[%{DATA:data7}] \[%{DATA:data8}] \[%{DATA:data9}] \[%{DATA:data10}] \[%{DATA:data11}] %{DATA:data12}-%{DATA:data13}-%{DATA:data14}%{GREEDYDATA:message}     : %{DATA:data15} %{DATA:data16} %{DATA:data17} %{DATA:data18} %{GREEDYDATA:message2}"
  add_field => [ "[@metadata][found_cf_match]", "true" ]
}
output {
stdout { codec => rubydebug }
codec => json
elasticsearch { 
hosts => ["hostname"]
index => "indexv"
user => "username"
password => ""
document_type => "_doc"
}
}
```

We are able to parse this actual cloud foundry loge message as per the logstash configuration grok pattern in the online grok pattern validator tools.

[grok pattern test result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRJVv.png)

Expecting the json message to be stored in message2 fields in elastic search and view it using kibana